# Linq return null for no results

Tags: c#, linq

In the following simplified example, I want to set Containers to `null` should there be no no matches.

```
_viewModel.Materials = _jobMaterials.Select(x=> new {

    //Containers that the material my be in
    Containers = (materialContainers.Where(mcl => mcl.Field<string>("MATKey") == x.Field<string>("MATKey")).Any()) ?
                    materialContainers.Where(mcl => mcl.Field<string>("MATKey") == x.Field<string>("MATKey")).Select(mcl => new
                    {
                        Id = mcl.Field<int>("SERIDNumber"),
                        Description = mcl.Field<string>("SERDescription").Trim(),
                        Volume = mcl.Field<int>("SERVolume"),
                        ContractedStatus = mcl.Field<int>("Contracted"),
                        OnJob = Convert.ToBoolean(mcl.Field<int>("OnJob"))
                    }) : null

});
```

The above works, but is there a more succinct method? Like a combination of `DefaultIfEmpty` and `FirstOrDefault`.

Neither works in isolation, `FirstOrDefault` returns a single item when there are multiple matches whereas `DefaultIfEmpty` returns a collection containing `null` if there are no matches.

Comment: Nothing built-in. Define yourself a helper method. Right now the query code is highly redundant and unreadable.

Comment: Agreed, hence the query ;) Thanks, makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a helper method

```
public static IEnumerable<object> NullIfEmpty(this IEnumerable<object> item)
{
        return item.Any() ? item : null;
}
```

Usage:

```
_viewModel.Materials = _jobMaterials.Select( material => new {

    //Containers that the material my be in
    Containers = materialContainers.Where(mcl => mcl.Field<string>("MATKey") == material.Field<string>("MATKey"))
                .Select( mcl => new {
                            Id = mcl.Field<int>("SERIDNumber"),
                            Description = mcl.Field<string>("SERDescription").Trim(),
                            Volume = mcl.Field<int>("SERVolume"),
                            ContractedStatus = mcl.Field<int>("Contracted"),
                            OnJob = Convert.ToBoolean(mcl.Field<int>("OnJob"))
                        })
                .NullIfEmpty()

});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
_viewModel.Materials = _jobMaterials
.Select(x=>materialContainers.Where(mcl => mcl.Field<string>("MATKey") == x.Field<string>("MATKey")))
.Select(m => new {
      //Containers that the material my be in
       Containers = m.Any() ?
                    m.Select(mcl => new
                    {
                        Id = mcl.Field<int>("SERIDNumber"),
                        Description = mcl.Field<string>("SERDescription").Trim(),
                        Volume = mcl.Field<int>("SERVolume"),
                        ContractedStatus = mcl.Field<int>("Contracted"),
                        OnJob = Convert.ToBoolean(mcl.Field<int>("OnJob"))
                    }) : null
```

Answer (score 0):

use  DefaultIfEmpty Function first then Select 
example:
    data.collection.Where(i => i.Type == type)
               .DefaultIfEmpty(defaultObject)
               .Select(i => i.Count);